# If statement is being registered as a variable in my Dart Flutter code? How do I change this?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, dart-pub, flutter-test

[image: The highlighted text is giving me errors like those shown in my Problems console. I've never receieved these kinds of issues when dealing with if statements, and I'm wondering why they are no registering as if statements. In one of the errors it says "if is already defined", but its not a variable. How do I solve this? Does it have anything to do with the async functions? I struggled with these.]

The highlighted text in the image is giving me errors like those shown in my Problems console. I've never receieved these kinds of issues when dealing with if statements, and I'm wondering why they are no registering as if statements. In one of the errors it says "if is already defined", but its not a variable. How do I solve this? Does it have anything to do with the async functions? I struggled with these

### I am trying to request the user location data for a map I plan to implement in a flutter App, but it's not working :/ SOMETHING is wrong with my ifs that I can't solve.

```
Future<bool> assignService(Location loc) async {
  bool servicestatus = await loc.serviceEnabled();
  return servicestatus;
}

Future<PermissionStatus> assignPermission(Location loc) async {
  return await loc.hasPermission();
}

Future<LocationData> assignLocation(Location loc) async {
  return await loc.getLocation();
}

Location location = new Location();

var _serviceEnabled = assignService(location);

if (_serviceEnabled != true) {
  _serviceEnabled = assignService(location);
  if (!_serviceEnabled) {
    return;
  }
}

var _permissionGranted = assignPermission(location);

if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) async{
  _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
  if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
    return;
  }
}

var _locationData = assignLocation(location);
```

Update (code before that above):

```
  Future<bool> assignService(Location loc) async {
  bool servicestatus = await loc.serviceEnabled();
  return servicestatus;
}

Future<PermissionStatus> assignPermission(Location loc) async {
  return await loc.hasPermission();
}

Future<LocationData> assignLocation(Location loc) async {
  return await loc.getLocation();
}

Location location = Location();

var _serviceEnabled = assignService(location);

var _permissionGranted = assignPermission(location);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote code outside a function. 
Only variable declaration can be outside a function, not code.

For example you can do :

```
  void StartService() {
    if (_serviceEnabled != true) {
      _serviceEnabled = assignService(location);
      if (!_serviceEnabled) {
        return;
      }

    if (_permissionGranted == PermissionStatus.denied) async{
      _permissionGranted = await location.requestPermission();
      if (_permissionGranted != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
```

The if shouldn't be outside code block.
You have to put it in a function. That's explain your error.

Tell me if you need more details.

Edit : just for information, the "new" keyword is not needed in flutter anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much! The if statements now operate. But i Have come accross another issue with regard to the first 2 if statements. This is the error message: "A negation operator must have a static type of bool", I think this is because it is still a future, but how do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is very simple `if` can't be the member of a class you should do `if` checks inside a function.

```
void doIfChecks(){
// if statements
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! The if statements now operate. But i Have come accross another issue with regard to the first 2 if statements. This is the error message: "A negation operator must have a static type of bool", I think this is because it is still a future, but how do I change this?

Comment: You can simply add await keyword in front of a future inside if statement

Comment: How would I add this to my code? Would I not need an async aswell? Also I have already awaited the value in my function, why would I need to do it twice? Thank you again

Comment: Use await when assigning variables _seriveEnabled and _permissionGranted so you don't need toh use await in if statements and you need to use await the methods returns future.